# JSDoc: document generic type that works for grandchildren classes

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jsdoc

Documenting generic type works for direct inheritance. But when I have a inheritance chain, there is no way to make it work for the grandchildren class. Here is an example:

```
 * @property {string} color
 * @template {T}
 */
class MyColor {
  constructor() {
    this.color = 'unknown';
  }

  /**
   * @returns {T}
   */
  static makeColor() {
    return /**@type {T}*/ new this.prototype.constructor();
  }
}

/**
 * @extends MyColor<Red>
 * @template {T}
 */
class Red extends MyColor {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.color = 'red';
  }
}

/**
 * @extends Red<DarkRed>
 */
class DarkRed extends Red {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.level = 2;
  }

  darker() {
    this.level += 1;
  }
}

const circle = DarkRed.makeColor();
```

`DarkRed.makeColor` only recognizes the return as `Red`, but not `DarkRed`. Is there a way to make it work with `@template`? Or is there any other way to make it work?

I am using WebStorm as the IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types#inheritance-of-generic-types, `@extends MyColor<Red>` 'fixes' the template type instead of propagating it to inheriting type. For example, in

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @template T
 */
var A = function() { };

/** @param {T} t */
A.prototype.method = function(t) {  };

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {A<string>}
 */
var B = function() {  };

/**
 * @constructor
 *
 * @extends {B<number>}
 */
var C = function() {  };


var cc =new C();
var bb = new B();

var bm = bb.method("hello");
var cm = cc.method(1);
```

`cc.method(1)` will result in `TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of A.prototype.method does not match formal parameter
found   : number
required: string`

You can try changing your code to

```
/**
* @property {string} color
 * @template {T}
 */
class MyColor {
  constructor() {
    this.color = 'unknown';
  }

  /**
   * @returns {T}
   */
  static makeColor() {
    return /**@type {T}*/ new this.prototype.constructor();
  }
}

/**
 * @extends MyColor<T>
 * @template {T}
 */
class Red extends MyColor {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.color = 'red';
  }
}

const circle1 = Red.makeColor();

/**
 * @extends Red<DarkRed>
 *
 */
class DarkRed extends Red {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.level = 2;
  }

  darker() {
    this.level += 1;
  }
}

const circle = DarkRed.makeColor();
```

another possible solution is using `@return {this}` instead of `@template` (works since 2018.2):

```
class MyColor {
  constructor() {
    this.color = 'unknown';
  }

  /**
   * @return {this}
   */
  static makeColor() {
    return  new this.prototype.constructor();
  }
}


class Red extends MyColor {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.color = 'red';
  }
}

class DarkRed extends Red {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.level = 2;
  }

  darker() {
    this.level += 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for `DarkRed`, but `Red.makeColor()` will not recognize the return as `Red`.

Comment: I guess you can't fix the type and propagate it to inheriting type at the same time using JSDoc:(

Comment: Then I guess it's a limitation of JSDoc, not WebStorm. Do you think there is other way to do it with JSDoc without using template?

Comment: you can remove all JSdoc comments and just use `/**
   * @return {this}
   */
  static makeColor() {}`; but htis only works since 2018.2 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33061)

Comment: see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33603#focus=streamItem-27-2930696-0-0

Comment: please update your answer and I will accept it. Thanks @lena